# XSL-FO: How to prevent Instream foreign object from being trimmed?

Tags: xslt, svg, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP to generate a PDF that contains an instream-foreign-object element whose content is a svg document.  I am having a problem where the leftmost edge is seemingly being trimmed off like so: [image]

These images are placed in a table.  The size of each containing table cell is set by the width and height attributes in the SVG.  I have tried modifying the width values and explicitly setting overflow attributes to 'visible.'  None of which works.  I should say that when the app is run on a Windows machine this clipping does not occur, but on Linux this is seen.  I don't know if that's a problem or not as the W3C docs mention overflow can be handled differently based on OS.

Included are the relevant parts of the XSL from the flow element as well as the template that applies the svg to the template.  Can anyone help?

```
<fo:page-sequence id="chartsPage" master-reference="landscape">
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="exports/export" />
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <fo:block id="headersBlock" margin-top="0.5in" font-family="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" color="#5c068c" font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="exports/export/headers"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block id="chartBlock" text-align="center">
                            <fo:table>
                                <fo:table-body>
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="exports/export/charts/chart" />
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </fo:table-body>
                            </fo:table>
                        </fo:block>...</fo:flow>
```

Here's the chart template element.  Each input chart element contains an svg document:

```
<xsl:template match="chart">
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block width="{svg:svg/@width}px">
            <fo:instream-foreign-object width="80%" content-width="scale-to-fit" content-height="100%" scaling="uniform">
                <svg:svg width="{svg:svg/@width}" height="{svg:svg/@height}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="svg:svg"/>
                </svg:svg>
            </fo:instream-foreign-object>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the svg for the above image.  Please note the image included in this post clipped out chart title and some other text.  They are appearing correctly in all cases.  I only attached the trouble spot.

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="400">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="highcharts-59">
        <rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="9999" height="400" stroke-width="0.000001"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="highcharts-60">
        <rect fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="757" height="210"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="#FFFFFF" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="400" stroke-width="0.000001"/>
<g class="highcharts-grid" />
<g class="highcharts-grid" >
    <path fill="none" d="M 33 215.5 L 790 215.5" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1" />
    <path fill="none" d="M 33 145.5 L 790 145.5" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1" />
    <path fill="none" d="M 33 75.5 L 790 75.5" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1" />
    <path fill="none" d="M 33 285.5 L 790 285.5" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1" />
</g><g class="highcharts-axis" >
    <path fill="none" d="M 789.5 285 L 789.5 290" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path fill="none" d="M 33 285.5 L 790 285.5" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"  visibility="visible"/>
</g><g class="highcharts-axis" />
<g class="highcharts-series-group" >
    <g class="highcharts-series" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(33,75)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-60)">
        <rect fill="#00569b" x="151" y="41" width="228" height="169" stroke-width="0.000001" stroke="#FFFFFF" rx="0" ry="0"/>
    </g><g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(33,75)" clip-path="none"/>
    <g class="highcharts-series" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(33,75)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-60)">
        <rect fill="#80abcd" x="378" y="31" width="228" height="179" stroke-width="0.000001" stroke="#FFFFFF" rx="0" ry="0"/>
    </g><g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(33,75)" clip-path="none"/>
    <g class="highcharts-series" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(33,75)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-60)">
        <path fill="none" d="M 0 0" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"   stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 0 0" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"   stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 0 0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"   stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 0 0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" />
    </g><g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(33,75)" clip-path="none">
        <path fill="#000000" d="M 378.50000000000006 67.1 C 383.82800000000003 67.1 383.82800000000003 75.1 378.50000000000006 75.1 C 373.1720000000001 75.1 373.1720000000001 67.1 378.50000000000006 67.1 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.000001"/>
    </g>
</g>
<text x="395" y="25" style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#3e576f;font-weight:bold;fill:#3e576f;" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" >
    <tspan x="395">XXXXXXXX XXXXXX</tspan>
</text>
<path fill="none" d="M 33 146 L 790 146" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" />
<g class="highcharts-legend"  transform="translate(353,295)">
    <g  clip-path="url(#highcharts-59)">
        <g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"  transform="translate(8,3)">
                <path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000"/>
                <path fill="#000000" d="M 8 7 C 13.328 7 13.328 15 8 15 C 2.6719999999999997 15 2.6719999999999997 7 8 7 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.000001"/>
                <text x="21" y="15" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#3e576f;font-weight:normal;padding-bottom:10;fill:#3e576f;" text-anchor="start" >
                    <tspan x="21">U.S. Total</tspan>
                </text>
            </g><g class="highcharts-legend-item"  transform="translate(8,32)">
                <text x="21" y="15" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#3e576f;font-weight:normal;padding-bottom:10;fill:#3e576f;" text-anchor="start" >
                    <tspan x="21">Current</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect rx="2" ry="2" fill="#80abcd" x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" stroke-width="0.000001"  stroke="#80abcd"/>
            </g><g class="highcharts-legend-item"  transform="translate(8,61)">
                <text x="21" y="15" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#3e576f;font-weight:normal;padding-bottom:10;fill:#3e576f;" text-anchor="start" >
                    <tspan x="21">Previous</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect rx="2" ry="2" fill="#00569b" x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" stroke-width="0.000001"  stroke="#00569b"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels" >
    <text x="411.5" y="299" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;width:737px;color:#666;line-height:14px;fill:#666;" text-anchor="middle"/>
</g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels" >
    <text x="33" y="290" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:8.6px;width:359px;color:#666;line-height:14px;fill:#666;" text-anchor="end">
        <tspan x="33">0.00%</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="33" y="220" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:8.6px;width:359px;color:#666;line-height:14px;fill:#666;" text-anchor="end">
        <tspan x="33">20.00%</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="33" y="150" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:8.6px;width:359px;color:#666;line-height:14px;fill:#666;" text-anchor="end">
        <tspan x="33">40.00%</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="33" y="80" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:8.6px;width:359px;color:#666;line-height:14px;fill:#666;" text-anchor="end">
        <tspan x="33">60.00%</tspan>
    </text>
</g><g class="highcharts-tracker" >
    <g visibility="visible"  transform="translate(33,75)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-60)">
        <rect fill="rgb(192,192,192)" x="151" y="41" width="228" height="169" isTracker="1404735525027" fill-opacity="0.0001" visibility="visible" style=""/>
    </g><g visibility="visible"  transform="translate(33,75)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-60)">
        <rect fill="rgb(192,192,192)" x="378" y="31" width="228" height="179" isTracker="1404735525028" fill-opacity="0.0001" visibility="visible" style=""/>
    </g><g visibility="visible"  transform="translate(33,75)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-60)">
        <path fill="none" d="M 368.50000000000006 71.1 L 388.50000000000006 71.1" isTracker="true" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke-opacity="0.0001" stroke="rgb(192,192,192)" stroke-width="22" style=""/>
    </g>
</g>
```

Thanks,

Brandt

Comment: If there is a difference between OSes then check what XSLTprocessor you are using on each. Is it the same? Are you sure the very same FO is passed? If java matches and Xslt matches and FOP version matches, it should not be different.

Comment: Does the svg have a viewbox? Perhaps you should post a sample svg also. I have seen this with some charting svgs because the viewbox is set improperly and the svg has right aligned labels on the y-axis

Comment: @KevinBrown I have attached the svg for the above image.  I did not see any viewBox elements in the svg document.  We are using the default XSLT processor with FOP: Xalan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I know the issue and it likely explains the apparent difference in OS. Highcharts likely calculated all positions based on font size which comes from the actual font used. The x-axis labels are positioned at 33 anchored right. You are formatting that in two different instances of FOP, one has the same font Highcharts used or one similar. One has a larger font but still matches the font choice on the text (see the list of fonts in the SVG). The larger one results in a slightly longer text span, larger than 33.

My guess based on the font list is that Windows used Verdana and Linux used Helvetica. Check this and either ensure you have the same fonts on all platforms or set a viewbox in the svg the is slightly larger with neg x.

In testing my guess, here is your SVG twice in same output. I only changed the font selection in the SVG to force different fonts. You can see the difference. Likely the font in your "clipped" environment is larger than what was used to determine the spacing in the SVG.

[image]

To prove that point in comments below, using you exact SVG I just added more characters (simulating a larger font width). You see, I put in the word "CUTOFFF" and it is cut off. It would not shift "after" it is calculated by Highchart and any scaling you do in FO is meanlingless. The text is outside the SVG.

[image]

Comment: Your guess about fonts may be correct.  If I change the font to Verdana on the Linux server the label does in fact fit.  What has confused me most, though is after having set the size of the block containing the svg, should 'scale-to-fit' have ensured the svg inside the instream-foreign-object fit inside the cell?

Comment: Nope. It is because the SVG is calculated at the time you rendered with that font. Using the wrong (larger) font ddoes not change the fact that the SVG says "put this text at X = 33, right-anchored". those labels in the wrong font are likely 34 or 35 wide and therefore outside of the SVG (x=-1). Since you have no viewport, it is assumed to go from 0,0 to width,height. Thus, the edge of that text is clipped. That is why when i do this I always insert a viewBox in the SVG giving it a bit of space (like -5, -5, width+5, height+5).

Comment: And I would note the image above would be different if it did what you thought. The left sides would be aligned and the text left alignment the same. The second image uses a smaller font (same font size, but smaller glyphs) than the first one. The right side of the "%" symbol is in the exact same spot in each. Only the text grows longer left based on glyph size and the one used to calculate the SVG in the first place was smaller then the one you used to render in FOP. Hence, it is cut off.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation & examples.  Will the fact that these charts are displayed in a table cell add any confounding effects?  My guess is it shouldn't.

Comment: None. It is outside the bounds of the rendered SVG. You could "guess" at how much space you need and do something like I said before (viewBox). For instance, take your SVG that is being cutoff and add this in the svg tag: viewBox="-5, -5, 805, 405" ... since your SVG is 800 wide by 400 high. This essentially has the effect of making the view port 5px larger all around. Thus, a slight overage (less than 5px) would now fit.